# Add a single line in histogram

Tags: r

This is an R question.

I want to add a vertical line at the position of mean value in histogram.

My code is:

```
abline(h=0,v=mg,col="red")#mg is the mean value.
```

But there are two lines come out, except the one I want, also a horizontal line along with X-axis show up.

How can I generate only one line (the vertical line) I want?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should not be mixing 'h' and 'v' as arguments to `abline`. I suppose my initial thought that it should be generating a warning is not correct, since you are describing the manner in which the "warning" is being delivered.

Answer (score 20):

Omit the `h` argument. Each addition to the `h` and `v` arguments in `abline` generates a line.

```
abline(v=mg,col="red")
```